# Outputting to TV screen issue. Black bar around screen and crashes on graphic heavy processes

Tags: windows-7, crash, amd-radeon, border

I am running Windows 7 SP1 on an AMD Phenom X4 with a Radeon 6770 1GB graphics card and 8GB RAM.

The computer runs fine until I try to output to my TV instead of computer monitor. I have a persistent "black bar" around my TV output no matter what I do. On the Catalyst control centre on the Digital Flat Panels bit, I have tried to use a custom format and on that screen it outputs to the full size of the TV screen so I know my PC can send a full sized output.

Even the over-scanning option doesn't work to get it to scale. It is a generic 37" LCD TV which is 1080p.

Whenever I try to run a graphics heavy program, particularly new games, after about 5 minutes (usually less) the whole thing will just crash and my PC will reboot. This doesn't happen if I run it through the monitor.

Lastly, and I don't know if this is important but for some reason when I do the windows key + P to switch between different modes, it seems to think my computer monitor is the "projector" and the TV is the "Computer only" option.

I am connecting my monitor by DVI, and the TV by HDMI.

UPDATE (response to first comment):

Yes tried it with both monitors and it still crashes and has black bar. Basicallt it seems to be an issue my set up has with my tv. And on the audio I am using a direct audio cable to my amplifier from back of PC.

Comment: Um... are you running the sound through the TV when you route the display to it?  Dumb question but also, have you tried running both monitors simultaneously as an extended desktop?

Comment: Yes tried it with both monitors and it still crashes and has black bar. Basicallt it seems to be an issue my set up has with my tv. And on the audio I am using a direct audio cable to my amplifier from back of PC.

Comment: Ralph Ferrett, edit your original post to add additional and requested information and leave the "Answer" section for actual answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Crashes can be caused by overheating. Use SpeedFan or similar to make sure your temps stay below 60 C idle and not much more active. Check fans, remove dust, and improve airflow for better cooling. Perhaps the heatsink's thermal paste is lacking.
2. If it's not a thermal issue, make sure you're using the latest stable drivers for your hardware. This might be an older version than advertised. Boot to Safe Mode by pressing F8 during startup for easy installation.
3. Check your display settings for proper native resolution and ratio, and adjust overscan settings in Catalyst Control Center and possibly on your TV.